# KNN algorithm, does the test points become training set?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, knn, nearest-neighbor

I understand the concept of the Knn Algo but i have a question. After we have classified new arriving test points , these test points become a part of our classification process? I mean, the future test points can get as closest points even pre-classified test points, or only the real and initial training points?

Comment: No. Calling predict is not changing the internal-representation of data. Why should it: you don't have a label or you would not be calling predict.

Comment: No maybe i did not explain myself. I means, after that a test point A has been classified, if a new test point B fall closest the point A. Supposing K=1,  does B will get the label of A even if A it's not a training point? I mean, does test point can get as referement for classification others previous test points or only the training points ?

Comment: I already said no. You never did tell your classifier that A is a training-point with some label y. So there is nothing to use.

Comment: I agree with @sascha and posted an answer. Sascha and rollotommasi, could you take a look please? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After we have classified new arriving test points , these test points become a part of our classification process?

*No*.

A test point gets classified and doesn't modify your initial dataset. So, if your dataset has 100 points, after a test point has arrived and been classified, your dataset will still have 100 points, *not* 101 points.

With that said, a test point will get classified towards the exactly same dataset, whether it arrives first or last (assuming that several other test points have already arrived).

Comment: I get it now ! Thank you both guys !